# ViewModel Unit test

Tags: android, kotlin, junit

I have a viewmodel that only emits the value of repo when I subscribe to it in the activity. I am trying to unit test the viewmodel (see code below) but I am getting NPE because repo is null. How can I unit test it? Is it possible?

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(mainRepository: MainRepository) : ViewModel() {

    val repo: LiveData<Resource<List<Repository>>> = mainRepository.getRepositories()
    
}
```

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class MainViewModelTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private val mainRepository = mock(MainRepository::class.java)
    private lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    
    @Before
    fun init() {
        mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mainRepository)
    }

    @Test
    fun testGetRepos() {
        mainViewModel.repo.observeForever(mock()) /* NPE at this point as repo is null*/
        verify(mainRepository).getRepositories()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface something like `IMainRepository` have your actual repository class implement it

```
class MainRepository : IMainRepository
```

Then change your ViewModel constructor to accept the interface

```
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(mainRepository: IMainRepository) : ViewModel()
```

Then create a Mock class that implements the interface and what it is suppose to do

```
class MockMainRepository : IMainRepository
```

in your test create a new instance of the mock class and pass that to your ViewModel to test

```
private val mockMainRepository = MockMainRepository()

@Before
fun init() {
   mainViewModel = MainViewModel(mainRepository)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure what the MockMainRepository should do. I mean, my MainRepository class has just one method getRepositories that using NetworkBoundResource class, returns a LiveData<Resource<List<Repository>>> . Do I have to somehow create a method that returns LiveData<Resource<List<Repository>>>  without all the logic from NetworkBoundResource?

Comment: yeah that mock class is just going to return dummy data back to your ViewModel and your ViewModel will treat it like actual data from you real repository

Comment: okay, so now I am getting org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type MockMainRepository and is not a mock!